# How to clear a input array all elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined my form elements using the html array method like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="45" name="Apikey[key]">
<select name="Apikey[developer]">
```

How can I clear all Apikey array using jQuery?

The question is how to clear them? All possible forms fields must be cleared.

Comment: The question is to reset them?  That's just setting `$("el").val("");`.  But you have special characters in your jQuery selection string which will fail.

Comment: select elements don't go back when using val("")

Comment: You haven't asked about `select` elements.

Comment: I don't want a reset. I want all form elements to have no value. Checkboxes cleared, selects to -1 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to use the ["standard" form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) and call `clearForm()` or `clearFields()`:

```
$('#formId').clearForm();
$('#formId [name^=Apikey]').clearFields();
```

Or, if you don't want or need all the extra form plugin machinery, just grab the source and figure out how `clearForm()` and `clearFields()` work. `clearFields()` is actually quite simple:

```
$.fn.clearFields = $.fn.clearInputs = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var t = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (t == 'text' || t == 'password' || tag == 'textarea') {
            this.value = '';
        }
        else if (t == 'checkbox' || t == 'radio') {
            this.checked = false;
        }
        else if (tag == 'select') {
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try ^(starts with) in the selector instead of |.
Also to reset the fields appropriately storing the initial values using data.
i.e:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name^=Apikey]").each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data("initial-val", $this.val());
    });
});
.
.
.
function resetApiValues(){
   $("input[name^=Apikey]").each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.val($this.data("initial-val"));
   });
}
```

Comment: This is a good aproach as a selector, but doesn't mentioned how to clear them.

Comment: Updated the post to reset the value for filtered fields.

Comment: As I mentioned in the questions's comment section I don't need the reset function, I don't need to save the initial values. I would like to clear all filters.

Comment: The above code resets the form, that means it puts back all the values as it was when the page loaded initially. Instead I am looking to clear all the form elements, and I don't care about their initial values. The val() doesn't work on checkboxes/radios and selects.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
$("input[name^='Apikey']").attr("name", "");
```

to clear the values:

```
$("input[name^='Apikey']").val("");
```

I see that you have edited to include different HTML elements, in that case:

```
$("*[name^='Apikey']")).each(function() { 
    switch(this.type) { 
        case 'password': 
        case 'select-multiple': 
        case 'select-one': 
        case 'text': 
        case 'textarea': 
            $(this).val(''); 
            break; 
        case 'checkbox': 
        case 'radio': 
            this.checked = false; 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> $('input[name^="Apikey"]')...

See [the official jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) here. bye

Comment: This is a good aproach as a selector, but doesn't mentioned how to clear them.

Answer (score -1):

You cant just clear all the values. Some elements like SELECT have to have a value.